# android - Include a xml layout from another package

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, package

I work with two packages in my android project.

The first package called `Core.Android` have a xml layout called LeftMenu.

I want to include this xml in each activity of my second package called `Android.Phone`.

I tried something like this in my activity's layout :

```
<include layout="@[Core.Android]layout/LeftMenu" />
```

but seems it didn't work.

Can you help me please ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use your layout the normal way : `@layout/LeftMenu`. You need to fix your android module to use your Core.Android module as a dependency.

You can do that in IntelliJ/AndroidStudio in the project settings, in "Modules", select your Android.Phone module and then go the "Dependencies" tab and add your Core.Android module with Compile scope.

Comment: Core.Android is already in the Dependencies of Android.Phone :/

Comment: Hi Cyrillie, I am using the layout from another module. It compiles and it works fine. However, the preview doesn't work (ie. when I click on "Design", it displays blank screen). Any idea?